# Error 404 while trying to POST JSON to PHP using JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I am setting up a server using surveyjs library and am looking to connect it to an personal database that is hosted locally,

I am having trouble going from javascript and sending the json file to php and then sending that information to the database.

Have tried to you XLMHttp code to send json file but it wont post and I am getting a 404 not found error inside of the developer tools

This is my entire js file excluding the JSON

```
function sendDataToServer(survey) {
    survey.sendResult('b48f3bcb-3978-4486-aa30-22cf94092850');
}

var survey = new Survey.Model(surveyJSON);
$("#surveyContainer").Survey({
    model: survey,
    onComplete: sendDataToServer
});

survey.onComplete.add(function (sender, options) {

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.open("POST", "connect.php", true);

      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

      xhr.send(JSON.stringify(sender.data));
});
```

This is the php file

```
//Decode the JSON string and convert it into a PHP associative array.
$data = json_decode($_POST['sender'], true);
```

This is the specific line that is causing the error

```
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(sender.data));
```

Comment: Not found means just that... The URL was not found.  What is the full URL of the AJAX request being made?  Is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: Why as you are using jQuery code all over the rest of the code dont you use jQuery to make the ajax call. It is so much easier

Comment: please make sure your js file and connect.php both are in same folder not in subfolder based on your code, otherwise use directory structure or url in xhr request to point to right path, so your xhr will find the request to where you are sending data

Comment: @RajenderVerma I moved the php file in the same folder as the js still receiving the error " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @RiggsFolly you recommend using jquery to POST to php instead? I can do that through the ajax function correct

Comment: @David how do I check for that?

Comment: @overwhelmed: In your browser's developer tools, in the Network tab.

Comment: @David http://127.0.0.1:55283/js/connect.php it what it shows now. As I moved it into the same folder as my js file.